# Can't see any products in opencart admin panel

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I made website in opencart, there were some demo products, ive seen them in admin as well as on frontend.

I renamed them all to the same name for placeholder purpose.

Suddenly they all dissapeard from admin but not from frontend.

After i added new product with different name, it showed on the frontend but not admin.

I deleted all products tru database, hoping it will fix it. I added new product. Product showed up on frontend but not in admin.
I have no idea whats wrong.
I dont have any filters tuned on.
Opencart is version 2.3.0.2

Do you know what can cause this problem ? Im working with OC for a long time and never experienced anything like this. Thank you

Comment: have you checked the database if there is any problem in the entries?

Comment: i can see every product in database, also something weird happened, yesterday i suddenly saw products, and today they dissapeared again from admin but everything is ok in frontend

Comment: you should check your user permissions...might be some problem there